# How to know if user rejected the Location Services in Swift 2

Tags: swift2, cllocationmanager

I'm trying to make location service app and i have the following code so when the user goes to that view controller he will get an alert of getting the current location.

This is the code

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
// 1. status is not determined
        if CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() == .NotDetermined {
            locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
        }
            // 2. authorization were denied
        else if CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() == .Denied {



            SwiftSpinner.hide()
            let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Error with Your Location" , message: "Location services were previously denied. Please enable location services for this app in Settings.", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
            let ok = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default) {
                UIAlertAction in
                UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(NSURL(string: UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString)!)


            }
            alert.addAction(ok)
            let cancel = UIAlertAction(title: "Back", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default) {
                UIAlertAction in

                self.movenav("arxiki")

            }
            alert.addAction(cancel)
            self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

        }
            // 3. we do have authorization
        else if CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() == .AuthorizedAlways {
            locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
        }


        self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(false, animated: true)

       self.eventsTable.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGrayColor()

       // self.locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()

        if CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled() {
            locationManager.delegate = self
            locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyNearestTenMeters
            locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
        } 

    }
```

My question is the following.
If the user pushes "Do not authorise" How can i get his option so i can send him back to the previous view controller or to alert him with the message that i have?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to catch the user selection you need to declare a CLLocationManager object and implement its delegate (CLLocationManagerDelegate) and use the following method for catching it.

```
func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didChangeAuthorizationStatus status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {
    if status == .Denied || status == .NotDetermined{
       // User selected Not authorized
    }       
}
```

I assume you have already configured the info.plist with the suitable locations parameters.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thx. This did help.  Command has changed in Swift 5 to: func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didChangeAuthorization status: CLAuthorizationStatus)